# iPhone 1X / 2X Resolution issue in iPad iOS Version 8.4.1 - Cordova

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-build, ios8.4

**Update:** **It happens only at the initial time.when i minimize the application and open it again then it works just fine.**

Last week i submitted an iPhone Application to iTunes Store, they rejected the application by the following comments.

> 2.10 - iPhone Apps must also run on iPad without modification, at iPhone resolution, and at 2X iPhone 3GS resolution
>   2.10 Details
>
> We noticed that your app did not run at iPhone resolution when
>   reviewed on iPad running iOS 8.4.1, which is a violation of the App
>   Store Review Guidelines. We’ve attached screenshot(s) for your
>   reference.
>
> Next Steps
>
> Please revise your app to ensure it runs at iPhone resolution on iPad.

I tried to run the same iPhone build in iPad and it seems like there is an issue exist as they mentioned. In iOS 8.1.1 it works correctly when i click '1x / 2x' Zoom. but in iOS 8.4.1 the '2X' button is misplaced and small and i can't switch between '1x and 2x'.

Iam using cordova 3.6.3. Is it something to do with the cordova version? have some others encountered this problem? Iam in a tight schedule. can some please test this and confirm? Please let me know if any fix is available out there.

For screenshots, see below.
 
 
In iOS 8.1.1 
[image]

[image]

In iOS 8.4.1 
[image]

Comment: Can somebody explain why it is down voted? Down voting without comment? I you have any doubts then please ask. I really need to resolve this issue.

Comment: I don't think it's a cordova issue, but I'll take a look if it happens too on a native app using a regular webview. Why don't you make your app universal? if your app is responsive you will see it fine on the ipad

Comment: In native it works fine. i have checked it with one of my friend. i have another version of app for iPad. it's a client requirement to have both version of app separately.